# How to select from one table where difference with (sum) from another table?

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have two tables with following fields:
...

```
orders.orderID
orders.orderValue
```

and

```
payments.orderID
payments.payVal
```

In `payments.payVal` there will be incremental payments for each order (many-to-one).
What I need it so select ALL orders from `orders` where there is payment left `(orders.orderValue - ((sum)payments.payVal) > 0 )`.

The only thing I can come up to right now is a (foreach) using the `orderID`, but I cannot do that for some particular reasons. I also cannot add a column inside  table to hold the value for some reasons too.

What I need, is to perform the entire selection in one single SQL Query something that resembles this idea: `SELECT * FROM orders WHERE <... each(orderValue - (sum(payVal))) > 0 ...>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *, SUM(p.payVal) AS TotalPayed
FROM orders o
LEFT JOIN payments p ON o.orderID = p.orderID
GROUP BY o.orderID
HAVING SUM(p.payVal) < o.orderValue
```

This should provide you with the necessary fields, although I would advise you to select specific fields with this query.

The `LEFT JOIN` makes sure you get every order, even if there are no payments made yet.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0e7a8/1/0)

Comment: If you don't need the `TotalPayed` field, you can simply use
`SELECT * FROM [...]`.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like we came to the same solution,

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9a657/18

```
SELECT * FROM `orders`
LEFT JOIN `payments` AS p ON `orders`.`orderID` = p.`orderID`
GROUP BY `orders`.`orderID`
HAVING SUM(p.`payVal`) <= 0
```

Comment: I like both solutions, yours and @Marty McVry 's ... basically are the same. But, for some integration reasons, I will use your syntax. (I have automated my sql queries and the automation process fits better with your syntax). From Marty's I learned something interesting... thanks.

Comment: Actually, this query only gets where the total amount already payed is less then or equal to 0... That's not exactly what's needed here... (So, they are not the same...) Try executing my query on the sample data in this SQL Fiddle.